# Find .html() via .text()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a demo to find the closest parent html what contains specific `cursor position`.

HTML:

```css
[contenteditable=true] {
  border: 3px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<span contenteditable="true"><span id="sp1">[child span text 1]</span>[span text without child]<span id="sp2">[child span text 2]</span></span>
```

JavaScript code to get the caret index:

```
$.fn.extend({
    getCaretIndex: function () {
        var $self = $(this)[0], index = 0, sel, range;
        if (window.getSelection) {
            sel = window.getSelection();
            if (sel.rangeCount) {
                range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                if (range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode === $self) {
                    index = range.endOffset
                }
            }
        } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
            range = document.selection.createRange();
            if (range.parentElement() === $self) {
                var tempEl = document.createElement('span');
                $self.insertBefore(tempEl, $self.firstChild);
                var tempRange = range.duplicate();
                tempRange.moveToElementText(tempEl);
                tempRange.setEndPoint('EndToEnd', range);
                index = tempRange.text.length
            }
        }
        return index
    }
});

// In use:
var index = $('span[contenteditable="true"]').getCaretIndex();
```

**Requirement:** when I click on the `span[contenteditable="true"]`, I will find the caret index and get the html `$('span[contenteditable="true"]').html()` first.

```
$('span[contenteditable="true"]').click(function () {
    var $self = $(this),
        html = $self.html(),
        index = $self.getCaretIndex();
});
```

Then, if the index is inside `<span id="sp1">` tag, show that tag within `.text()` via `html`.

```
var tag = $('span#sp1'), text = tag.text();
```

Where I'm stuck: The `index` would be calculated via `$self.text()`. So, if I get the `html` to check where it is, that's wrong.

```
var html = $self.html();
var text = $self.text();
// html.length !== text.length
```

My question: how to get the html inside `<span contenteditable>` via caret index in this case?

More extension (if need):

```
String.prototype.contains = function (o) {
    'use strict';
    var $self = this;
    return $.type(o) === 'string' ? $self.indexOf(o) > -1 : ($self.match(o) || []).length > 0
};

// In use:
var contained = 'My string'.contains('str'); // true
var _contained = 'My string'.contains(/\s/); // true
```

I hope it's clearly!

Comment: Could you clarify your goal? I understood that `text` and `html` have different length, so it cause you some troubles with index position. But all other information is a mess...

Comment: @AlenaKastsiukavets Mess? I need to find cursor position first. Then, checking is it inside `<span id="sp1">` or not? If yes, show that tag. That's all.